# How do I create a client for Azure App Insights?

Tags: oracle, appinsights

I want to log to App Insights from Oracle database code. That is, pl/sql running within the database.

Is there an API guide that I can use to create a logging client? I haven't been able to find anything thus far within the online documentation, only references on how to use existing libraries for .NET, Java, etc.

Thanks so much.